# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent to activity

Tags: java, android

I m getting this error in my code.
Please help me.

My code is as follows. I don't know how to solve this. When I click on the add button I want to add all data to the model class and that class should be filled with the list array in main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DataTransferInterfase{
private Button btnSelect,btnShow;
    public int REQUEST_CAMERA=1;
    public int SELECT_IMAGE=0;
    private GridView gridview;
    private CustomAdapter gridAdaptor;
    public TextView tvcounter;
    public ImageItemBin imageItemBin;
    private Uri mCapturedImageUri;
public static ArrayList<ImageItemBin> publicSelectedImage=new ArrayList<ImageItemBin>();
    public  ArrayList<ImageItemBin> showImagelist=new ArrayList<ImageItemBin>();

    public Uri ImageUri;
    private int count=publicSelectedImage.size();
    private int coloumn=3;
    private int row=count/coloumn;

    public String imgPath="";
    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSelect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnselect);
        btnShow=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        tvcounter=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcounter);


        publicSelectedImage=new ArrayList<ImageItemBin>();
        //showImagelist=new ArrayList<ImageItemBin>();
        showImagelist=new ArrayList<ImageItemBin>();
        gridview=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout_main);
//        gridAdaptor=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,publicSelectedImage);
//        gridview.setAdapter(gridAdaptor);
        //gridAdaptor(R.layout.custom_grid_item_layout,getView());
        //gridLayout.addView(gridAdaptor.getView());
        //gridLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid_item_layout,null));
        //gridLayout.addView(img);

        //tvcounter.setText(CountRecord(imageItemBin));
        //tvcounter.setText(CustomAdapter.result+"");
        showImagelist.add(CustomAdapter.showBin);
        tvcounter.setText(showImagelist.size());
        //showImagelist.add(CustomAdapter.result);
        //tvcounter.setText(counter);

        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //custom dialogBox
                final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
                dialog.setTitle("Select from..");

                //set the custom dialog components
                TextView txtmsg=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
                Button btnGallaery=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btngallery);
                Button btnCamara=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncamara);

                btnGallaery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent image=new Intent();
                        image.setType("image/*");
                        image.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(image,"select file"),SELECT_IMAGE);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });




                btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent cam=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        /*if(cam.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                            String filename="temp.jpg";
                            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,filename);
                            mCapturedImageUri=getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);*/

                         //cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,setImageUri());

                        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

                        cam.putExtra("Image", fileUri);
                        startActivityForResult(cam,REQUEST_CAMERA);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                       // }


                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==SELECT_IMAGE){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && null!=data){
              for (int i=0,c=0,r=0;i<count;i++,c++){
                  if(c==coloumn){
                        c=0;
                        r++;
                   }

              }

                ImageUri=data.getData();
                imageItemBin=new ImageItemBin();
                imageItemBin.setImage(ImageUri.toString());
                publicSelectedImage.add(imageItemBin);

                gridAdaptor=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,publicSelectedImage,this);
                gridview.setAdapter(gridAdaptor);

            }
        }
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_CAMERA)
        {
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
                /*String[] projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor=managedQuery(mCapturedImageUri,projection,null,null,null);
                int coloumn_index_data=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String picturePath=cursor.getString(coloumn_index_data);
                Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
                imageItemBin=new ImageItemBin();
                imageItemBin.setImage(selectedImage.toString());
                publicSelectedImage.add(imageItemBin);*/

//                gridAdaptor=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,publicSelectedImage);
//                gridview.setAdapter(gridAdaptor);


                Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                String stringImage=BitMapToString(mphoto);

               // String getimage=getImagePath();


                imageItemBin=new ImageItemBin();
                imageItemBin.setImage(stringImage);
                //imageItemBin.setImage(picturePth.toString());
                publicSelectedImage.add(imageItemBin);
                gridAdaptor=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,publicSelectedImage,this);
                gridview.setAdapter(gridAdaptor);
                //gridAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

               // tvcounter.setText(counter);
                //publicSelectedImage=selectedImage;
            }
        }


    }


    public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }
    /*private List<ImageItemBin> DisplayImage(){
        ImageItemBin itembin=new ImageItemBin();
        itembin.getImage();
    }*/



    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        /*File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
*/
        //File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
       /*if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }*/

        // Create a media file name
        //String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
               // Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {

             mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");


        } /*else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            //mediaFile = new File(file.getPath() + File.separator
                   // + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        }*/ else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
        //return file;
    }


    private Bitmap previewCapturedImage(Uri file)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        try {
            // hide video preview
            //videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(),
                    options);

            return bitmap;
            //imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }


    public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return temp;
    }


    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try{
            byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static int totalAmt=0;

    @Override
    public int CountRecord(ImageItemBin bin) {
        //for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
            totalAmt=totalAmt+1;
       // }
        return totalAmt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it.
here is the way for getting the perfect result.in adapter just add the data.get(position)to countRecord method.

```
public int CountRecord(ImageItemBin bin)
{
    showImagelist.add(showBin);
    int size=showImagelist.size();
    tvcounter.setText(Integer.toString(size));
    btnShow.setText(Integer.toString(size));
    return 0;
}
```

CustomAdaptor.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public  static  String counter="";
public static int result=0;
Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<ImageItemBin> data=new ArrayList<ImageItemBin>();
public static  ImageItemBin showBin=new ImageItemBin();
DataTransferInterfase dataTransferInterfase;

String qty,title;
public MainActivity mainActivity;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity,ArrayList<ImageItemBin> data,DataTransferInterfase dataTransferInterfase){

    this.data=data;
    this.context=mainActivity;
    this.dataTransferInterfase=dataTransferInterfase;

    this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder=null;
    View rootview=convertView;

    if(rootview==null) {

        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid_item_layout, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.edttitle = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
        holder.edtqty = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.edtQty);
        holder.image = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.MyimageView);
        holder.tvcounter=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tvcounter);

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        rootview.setTag(holder);

        qty=holder.edtqty.getText().toString();
        title=holder.edttitle.getText().toString();
        data.get(position).setTitle(title);
        data.get(position).setQty(qty);




    }
    else
    {
        holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
        holder.image.setTag(position);
        holder.edttitle.setTag(position);
        holder.edtqty.setTag(position);


        qty=holder.edtqty.getText().toString();
        title=holder.edttitle.getText().toString();
        data.get(position).setTitle(title);
        data.get(position).setQty(qty);



    }

    String img=data.get(position).getImage();
    final String title=data.get(position).getTitle();
    final String qty=data.get(position).getQty();

    options = getDisplayImageOptions(context, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    imageLoader.displayImage(img, holder.image, options);


    holder.btnadd=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    final Holder finalHolder = holder;
    //public static final ImageItemBin showBin=new ImageItemBin();
    holder.btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data.get(position).setQty(qty);
            data.get(position).setTitle(title);
            showBin.setImage(data.get(position).getImage());
            showBin.setTitle(title);
            showBin.setQty(qty);
            mainActivity.CountRecord(data.get(position));

        }
    });

    return rootview;
}

 static class Holder{
    ImageView image;
    EditText edtqty;
    EditText edttitle;
     Button btnadd;
     TextView tvcounter;
}

public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayImageOptions(Context context, int defaultImg) {
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(defaultImg)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).showImageForEmptyUri(defaultImg).showImageOnFail(defaultImg)
            .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .considerExifParams(true).build();

    return options;
}
```

}